# Java serialization causes concurrency modification exception

Tags: java, serialization, concurrency

My program updates several hundred objects stored in an ArrayList about one hundred times per second. I've implemented Java's built in serialization, and it works well except when an attempt to serialize is made when the objects are going at it, in which case I may have to serialize a half dozen times before it works (each failed attempt throws an exception). I tried marking the arraylist as transient, but then when I loaded the serialization file, a null pointer exception is thrown. So I tried initializing the transient arraylist in the no args constructor, which did nothing to help. What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details - like some code? I would think that initialising the transient arraylist in the no args constructor should work, so I'm puzzled that it doesn't.

Comment: @Robin - deserialization does _not_ invoke any constructors or member intializers.

Comment: @jtahlborn -- so what is the point of the mandatory no args constructor?

Comment: If I temporarily stop the updating of the ArrayList objects, then serialize, it works no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you've synchronized access to your `ArrayList`, e.g. when you initialize it:

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

When you need to serialize it, grab a copy that will be consistent due to the synchronization:

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(list);
```

Now you can safely serialize out this copy without blocking access to the primary list.

Comment: the copy constructor for ArrayList will not copy the list in a threadsafe way.  you'd have to invoke that call in a `synchronized(list)` block.

Comment: @jtahlborn: the copy constructor for `ArrayList` will copy it in a thread-safe way if the list passed in is wrapped by `Collections.synchronizedList()` as I suggested. The constructor calls `toArray()` which will already be synchronized by that wrapper (see the `ArrayList` source). Using `synchronize (list)` will in fact not doing anything in this case as the object that the wrapped list uses to synchronize on is internal (see `SynchronizedCollection` inner class in `Collections` source). You'd be synchronizing on something different than the wrapper that's safeguarding the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate with foreach statement and modify your table.

Try to use

```
for (int i =0;i<arra.length;i++)
```

instead.

Comment: I am using the non-foreach loop. I probably should have tried static iterators before asking this.

Comment: So maybe you can synchronize access to you array.

Comment: Downvoted because this is an ArrayList not an Array, and it offers dangerous advice.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `ArrayList` to a new instance (shallow copy with `new ArrayList<>()` and serialize that.

Comment: how does this help? the copy will have all the same non-threadsafe problems as the serialisation copy.

Comment: Jed, that's incorrect. The copied array will not be modified (since it's different data). Unless the contained objects themselves are being modified in a non-thread-safe manner, this will be 100% safe.

Comment: my not very well written objection was that the copy construction would have the same fail-fast semantics, but as pointed out in the accepted answer, an ArrayList calls `toArray()` on the supplied collection in its copy ctor. This will not fail-fast. You still have thread-safety and visibility problems though and should really rethink use of shared ephemeral structures.

Comment: You could well be right that the copy itself might not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Iterator if you are traversing through the collection and concurrently modifying it.

Comment: That doesn't help when the concurrent modification is taking place in another thread, which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really don't want or need the list contents serialised declare your list member:

```
private transient final List<?> things = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You will always have a non-null list to work with.

That being said, from the sound of it your updates to the list itself may need to be thought about regarding other thread-safety issues such data-races and visibility issues.